# wordly Guess game Error StringIndexOutofBound error

Tags: java, swing, indexoutofboundsexception, stringindexoutofbounds

I am making a wordly type guess game using java swing ,trying to match two word (one from user input and second from txt file) and display it on gui label everything is working perfectly if i used the check_word as pre defined like String check_word = "moizz" but if i try to  get the word from txt file a error come , my both word are even same but it throws an error

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 5
```

here is my code in submit button

```
try{
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("E:\\WordyGame\\src\\wordygame\\targetWords.txt"));
    String line = reader.readLine();
    List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
    while(line != null) {
        String[] wordsLine = line.split(" ");
        for(String word : wordsLine) {
            words.add(word);
        }
        line = reader.readLine();
    }

    Random rand = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
    //getting random word from txt file
    String randomWord = words.get(rand.nextInt(words.size()));
    System.out.println(randomWord);
    String check_word = randomWord.trim().toLowerCase().toString();
    
    
    
    //getting user input
     String take_word = type_word.getText().toLowerCase().toString();
     System.out.println(take_word);
     
     //dividing word into char and then each char to strings
     //user input word 
      char first = take_word.charAt(1);
      String first1 =  String.valueOf(first);
      char second = take_word.charAt(2);
      String second1 =  String.valueOf(second);
      char third = take_word.charAt(3);
      String third1 =  String.valueOf(third);
      char fourth = take_word.charAt(4);
      String fourth1 =  String.valueOf(fourth);
      char fifth = take_word.charAt(5);
      String fifth1 =  String.valueOf(fifth);
      
      //random word from file
      
      char first2 = check_word.charAt(1);
      String first22 =  String.valueOf(first);
      char second2 = check_word.charAt(2);
      String second22 =  String.valueOf(second);
      char third2 = check_word.charAt(3);
      String third22 =  String.valueOf(third);
      char fourth2 = check_word.charAt(4);
      String fourth22 =  String.valueOf(fourth);
      char fifth2 = check_word.charAt(5);
      String fifth22 =  String.valueOf(fifth);
      
      
      
      
     
    if(take_word.length() < 7) 
    {
        if(first1.trim().equals(first22))
        {
                          word_1.setText(first1);
                          word_1.setBackground(Color.yellow);
        }
        else if(second1.trim().equals(second22))
        {

                          word_2.setText(second1);
                          
        }
        if(third1.trim().equals(third22))
        {
                          
                          word_3.setText(third1);
        }
        if(fourth1.trim().equals(fourth22))                
        {
                         
                          word_4.setText(fourth1);
                          
                          
        }
        if(fifth1.trim().equals(fifth22))
         {
                         
                          word_5.setText(fifth1);
                          //displaying charchter on GUI
        }                                  
    }
     else
     {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"only 5 char word are allowed Number");
     }
} catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
}
```

can someone help me out i tried different things but this error isn't solved

Comment: indices in java are 0 based, so 0 to 4, not 1 to 5

Comment: thanks its working i am beginner in java just never faces such problems before

Comment: `"//dividing word into char and then each char to strings"`.... why? I must be missing something here. Can't you just compare the random word with the word from User for equality?

Comment: hi actually the task is compare character of word no only word compare each charcter of word to another word and if charcter match display it else set text to unmacthed character and l;et user do this try 6 times

Comment: if you still didn't get it i could explain the whoile scenario